# PyCharm For Windows: Debugging Down / Up With Selection Executes Present Line

Tags: pycharm

Independant from the Keymapping:

Within Pycharm for Windows (Community Edition 2017-3, Build #PC-173.3727.137, built on November 28, 2017) I observe the following:

During a debugging session, I press the `Shift`-`Cursor Up` or `Shift`-`Cursor Down` (in order to mark and copy that line) .

As a result, that line gets executed in the Console.

How can I prevent this?

(it does not happen with Ubuntu, PyCharm Professional 2017.3)

reported with: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27971

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for the moment is, to deactivate the option `Show value tooltip on code selection` (in Settings/Debugger/Dataview).